# aggregated nondeliverable mail report o365

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365

My organization recently changed from internally managed exchange server to o365 mail.  Wondering if there is a report I can direct my admin to that aggregates non-deliervable emails with the email address that caused the bounce?

Comment: Seems like a *perfect* question to ask O365 support.

Answer (score 1):

As of today, other than 3rd party solutions like Cogmotive, the only way I'm aware of doing such a thing is through Powershell, there isn't a canned report in the admin console for this.

You can use the following to guide you into creating a script and can set it to run via a scheduled task if you want: [Office 365 Non Delivery Reports with Powershell](http://www.morgantechspace.com/2015/09/office-365-non-delivery-reports-with-powershell.html)